# using grep in a function in ubuntu terminal returns every line of the file instead of the lines that I'm looking for

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I' trying to write a script in bash. it is a to-do list maker. so the `find_tasks` function has a problem that I can't tell. I want to use grep to filter each line based on a pattern/ string.
this is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash

#initial file for saving tasks to
file=tasks.csv

#adding tasks to the list. 0 is for undone tasks. it is their default value.
function add_tasks {
    echo "0,$1,$2" >> "$file"
}

#when it is called it will clear the tasks.csv file
function clear_tasks {
    > "$file"
}

#it will show all of the tasks from the tasks.csv file in a formatted way
function list_tasks {
    awk -F',' '{print NR" | "$1" | "$2" | "$3}' "$file"
}

#it is for finding a specific task
function find_tasks {
    grep -i "$2" 
}


#calling the functions
case $1 in
    "add")
        task_name=$3
        if [[ -z $task_name ]]; then
            echo "Option -t|--title Needs a Parameter"
            exit
        fi
        priority=$5
        if [[ $priority != 'L' && $priority != 'M' && $priority != 'H' ]]; then
            echo "Option -p|--priority Only Accept L|M|H"
            exit
        fi
        add_tasks "$task_name" "$priority";;
    "clear")
        clear_tasks;;
    "list")
        list_tasks;;
    "find")
        find_tasks;;
    *)
        echo "Command Not Supported!"
esac
```

I have entered four entries to a file named `tasks.csv` by using `./todo.sh add -t "First Task" -p H`, `./todo.sh add -t "Second Task" -p M`, `./todo.sh add -t "Third Task" -p H`, and `./todo.sh add -t "Fourth Task" -p L`. now I want to use `./todo.sh find Second` for instance to have the second task like this: `0,Second Task,M`. but it prints out all of the lines from the `tasks.csv` file. so what should I do to have the appropriate line from the tasks.csv file based on the string I give to the grep command? what should I change in the `find_tasks` function to have the appropriate output?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, replace the `grep`  part with `grep -i "$2" "$file"`, you should be using an option parser for this tasks imo.

Comment: `find_tasks` uses its 2nd argument, but not its first argument. I find this approach odd. Why do you require this function to be called with 2 arguments, if one of them is thrown away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing arguments.

```
 find_tasks;;
          ^^^ - nothing
```

Pass the arguments.

```
 find_tasks "$@" ;;
```

Check your script with shellcheck.

Do not use `function name {`. Use `name() {`. See [here](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: The link seems to lead nowhere :-(

Comment: https://github.com/rawiriblundell/wiki.bash-hackers.org